# How to get index of an element on sorted hash

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

on my website i would like display the ranking of the top subscribers.

Here is my controller:

```
@users_top = User.all.sort_by{|e| e[:total_days_sub]}.reverse.first(10)
@users_sort = User.all.sort_by{|e| e[:total_days_sub]}.reverse
```

for the top 10 I have finished, the @users_top is ok.

But how can I have the index of an element of my hash @users_sort in depending of the current_user.email ?

Comment: A side note: please be aware that loading the whole table in memory (even worse - the whole horde of objects instantiated from the whole table) with `User.all` is extremely inefficient and can cause you serious troubles at scale. This job (sort, pick the top N records) should be delegated to the database in most practical cases...

Comment: You can write `@users_top = User.all.max_by(10) { |e| e[:total_days_sub]}`. See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by). Please edit to clarify your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to do

```
@users_sort = User.all.sort_by{|e| e[:total_days_sub]}.reverse.pluck(:email).find_index(current_user.email)
```